# Git hooks not firing OR clearing things up with git hooks

Tags: git, hook, bitbucket, githooks

I've read many articles on using git hooks, but don't quite get the whole picture. My set-up is the following: I'm working on a project for my company. I write code for a web-app on my mac, then I push it to a repo on bitbucket. In the company's local network, there is a virtual machine running a server. For now I remotely login to this VM and execute a `git pull` command if I've pushed a new piece of code to the repo. I want to configure a push-to-deploy scheme with git hooks, so basically whenever I push some new code into the repo, the VM should automatically pull it (you know, like some services allow you, e.g. Laravel Forge).

In the virtual machine there is a directory for the repo, say, `C:\project` (yes, it's running Windows, *sigh*). I've tried putting a `post-receive` hook into `C:\project\.git\hooks` directory with some "hello-world" code, like

```
#!/bin/sh
ECHO "HELLO"
pause
```

But it's not firing after I `git push` from my development environment. I *feel* like I'm doing something *totally* wrong here, but cannot find any solution. Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Okay, to clear things up, what I want to achieve:

1. I write some code on my mac and I `push` to a private repo on bitbucket;
2. The VM in my company's local network has this repository cloned already;
3. It figures out that there are some changes on bitbucket;
4. Using git-hooks, it runs some code to `pull` from bitbucket, like:

List item

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ../.. # cd back to project directory
git pull
npm install
bower install
...
```

6. I'm even ready to schedule a `git fetch` task if that's what is need for the case, but no hooks work.

Comment: The files should be in `C:\project\.git\hooks`, but maybe that was was you ment...

Comment: @joran, yeah, I meant, I've put it into hooks, ofc. Edited the original post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a post-merge hook on the VM server, since you do git pull there. post-receive is triggerd on the server where you do a git push to.

Move the post-merge hook to your remote repo to where you push.

**Edit:**

If you do a pull on A from a repo on B then post-merge on A is triggerd. If you push from A to a repo on B then post-receive on B is triggerd.

This may not be an option, but with Bitbucket webhooks you can notify a REST-service when a push event has happend in your project, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push.

There are plenty of alternatives to build a Rest-service that responds on push events (one alternative may be using Phyton scripts and GitPhyton, but there are plenty of other alternatives)

Comment: I won't be able to test it with the VM until monday, but I cloned my project on mac into another directory, and added a `post-merge` testing hook, but it doesn't fire anyway if I push from the original directory. Besides, I don't get it, this hook should be somehow **informed** about the fact that some changes took place in order to fire. How does this part happen?

Comment: I even tried `git fetch` in the second, cloned directory, so that git gets informed that there are some changes since last pull, but still nothing happens..

Comment: @AntonEgorov, `post-merge` is triggerd by a `git pull` on the side that initiated the command. If you do a pull on A from a repo on B then `post-merge` on A is triggerd. If you push from A to a repo on B then `post-receive` on B is triggerd.

Comment: that's what I came to understand, yes. The logic makes perfect sense, yes. What I'm trying to achieve is a sort-of-like Laravel Forge behavior, I push from A to B, and C somehow knows about changes in B and pulls the repo.